# website shortcut on android home screen prevent opening in chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I have my app setup using `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` and in [fullscreen](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/#launching_a_page_fullscreen_from_home_screen), so when I add the website as a shortcut to the homescreen it's in fullscreen and there's no addressbar. However there are still times when an "address bar" appears, it contains the URL, not editable, and the chrome options, which contains "Open in Chrome" button. How do I prevent this from appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such option. your web page is opening in [Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), you can't control this.

how to prevent? make native or PWA app. hiding website URL may lead to some security issues (maybe you will fake some bank site and force user to login - there is no URL and padlock to verify...)

Comment: Thank you, I will try a PWA since a native app isn't an option right now.